# Paginate search results in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, search, pagination, database-connection

I made a report of the databases created in a server, showing some row counters results from similar tables on those databases, using a table named Host to change the database configuration..Now I'm trying to add a simple search form in the same view to show only the macthed results. But I having problems with pagination.

In the HostController:

```
    <?php 
    class HostsController extends AppController {
public $paginate = array('limit' => 1); //just as a test    
function index() {
    $conditions = array();
    if(!empty($_GET['host_name'])){
        $asd=($_GET['host_name']);
        $asd=strtoupper($asd);
        $conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
    'upper(Host.client_name) LIKE' => "%$asd%",
    'upper(Host.contact_name) LIKE' => "%$asd%",
    'upper(Host.contac_email) LIKE' => "%$asd%"));
    }

    $hosts = $this->Host->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
    foreach ($hosts as $key => $host) {
        App::import('model','Product');
        $this->Product = new Product;
        $this->Product->changeDataSource($host['Host']['db_name']);
        if($this->changeDbSource($host['Host']['db_name'])) {

            $count = $this->Product->query('SELECT count(id) as "Product__count" from products');
            $hosts[$key]['Host']['count_products']= $count[0]['Product']['count'];
            $options = array(
                'conditions' => array(),
                'order' => array(
                'Product.created DESC'));
            $product = $this->Product->find('first', $options);
            $hosts[$key]['Host']['last_product'] = $product['Product'];
            }
        App::import('model','Sale');
        $this->Sale = new Sale;
        $this->Sale->changeDataSource($host['Host']['db_name']);
        if($this->changeDbSource($host['Host']['db_name'])) {
            $count = $this->Sale->query('SELECT count(id) as "Sale__count" from sales');
            $hosts[$key]['Host']['count_sales']= $count[0]['Sale']['count'];
            $options = array(
                'conditions' => array(),
                'order' => array(
                'Sale.created DESC'));
            $sale = $this->Sale->find('first', $options);
            $hosts[$key]['Host']['last_sale'] = $sale['Sale'];
        }   }
        $this->set(compact('hosts'));
        $this->paginate ();}///<<<<  Here is the problem?>
```

In the view:

```
    <form method="GET" >
    <input id="clientNameSearch" type="text" name="host_name" 
    value="<?php echo !empty($_GET['host_name']) ? 
    $_GET['host_name']:"";?>" placeholder="Client, Contact or email of the contact" > 
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

In the app controller(with a database config per row in hosts table):

```
    function changeDbSource($database = 'default') {
    $db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();
    $connected = $db->getDataSource($database);
    if($connected->isConnected()) {return true;} else {return false;}}
```

So, using just         $this->paginate ();             give me the WHOLE LIST of host table (or the search result) and doesnt paginate, only the leyend of the button result of

```
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => __());
```

in the view seems to work
I've been trying some variations on paginate() arguments, using conditions, definig a custom paginate() and others options suggested here with no positive result, probably because I'm new on this.

According to the documentation, I shoud be able to use:

```
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['host_name'])){
    $asd=($_GET['host_name']);
    $asd=strtoupper($asd);
     $this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
    'upper(Host.client_name) LIKE' => "%$asd%",
    'upper(Host.contact_name) LIKE' => "%$asd%",
    'upper(Host.contac_email) LIKE' => "%$asd%")
     ),'limit' => 2);}//just a test 
     if(empty($_GET['host_name'])) {$this->paginate();}?>
```

Still, no results.

So, if anyone know how to make it work or any suggestion, I'm all ears.
Thanks in advance(sorry for the poor english and coding).

### Solution:?

Since there was no anwsers..here is what I got:
I just put the next code before the foreach loops

```
    if (!empty($_GET['host_name'])){
        $getvar=($_GET['host_name']);
        $getvar=strtoupper($getvar);
        $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
            'upper(Host.client_name) LIKE' => "%$getvar%",
            'upper(Host.contact_name) LIKE' => "%$getvar%",
            'upper(Host.contac_email) LIKE' => "%$getvar%",
            'upper(Host.company_ruc) LIKE' => "%$getvar%")
             ),
        'limit' =>2);}   
    $hosts=$this->paginate ();
```

And in the Index.php:

```
    <?php 
$args = $_GET;
unset($args['url']);
$paginator->options( 
        array(
            'url' => $this->passedArgs + array('?'=>$args)
        )
);?>
```

It shows what I need, in the way I need, but the sort option apparenly doesnt work..I guess I wont use it

Comment: Since there was no anwsers..here is what I got:

Answer (score 0):

Add the search form in your view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Host'); 
echo $this->Form->text('keywords');
echo $this->Form->submit('Search');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Add the search form method in your controller:

```
$settings = array();
// Simple search method
if(! empty($this->request->data['Host']['keywords'])){
  $keywords = explode(' ',$this->request->data['Host']['keywords']);
  foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    $settings['conditions']['OR'][] = array('Host.foo Like' => '%'.$keyword.'%');
    $settings['conditions']['OR'][] = array('Host.bar Like' => '%'.$keyword.'%');
  }
}
$this->paginate = $settings;
    $this->set('hosts', $this->Paginator->paginate('Host'));
```

(Replace Host.foo and Host.bar with the columns you want to search in your hosts table - you can add more if you need to).

The standard Cake paginator will work for you in your index view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($hosts as $host): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo h($host['Host']['name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Remember the Paginator->sort('heading') must match the name of the column in your table, if you want a different title to show on your page you can use the second - title - argument i.e. Paginator->sort('column_name', 'Title to Display');

Should get you rolling.

Comment: but I have a question..how can I use the paginate function in the controller using this method?..since I havent defined any Host variable for paginate('Host')..I tried using $hosts = $this->Host->find('all', array('conditions'=>$settings));  $hosts=$this->paginate (); in order to keep using the next foreach functions..but the search part doesnt work this way..and doesnt paginate neither..Still.. using my pseudosoution of the post I just had to deactivate the sort part and everything else works fine..

Comment: The paginator is being used in the controller in the example I posted. As you can see from the code we first set $settings as an empty array variable: $settings = array();  Then we check for keywords returned from our form in the if statement. If the form has been submitted we populate the $settings variable with the kewords submitted. Then outside of the if statement we call cake's paginator component. This is used to set the $hosts variable. One thought - have you called the paginator component either in your app or hosts controller with: public $components = array('Paginator'); ?

Comment: Sorry..I wasnt clear in my last question..the thing is that adapting your method to my case threw me "Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object" error for        
        $this->set('hosts', $this->Paginator->paginate('Host'));
As you already noticed I'm really new on this (specially in MCV structure), but I have read about a possible issue mixing component pagination and controller paginate, So, no I havent called the paginator component. In fact I've never used it in that way

Comment: Anyway, The app is already working, but without any sort option for that table. Still, It would be nice if I can  make it fully work, just for the learning procces, I wouldnt mind if you give up on my case..Still thank you for your time.

Comment: To clarify: If you want to use pagination with cake you need to call in the paginator component. Without this cake won't have access to the paginator component class, this is why you were getting a call to a non-object error - the paginator object doesn't exist in your code as you haven't called it. So, you must add the line public $components = array('Paginator'); to the top of your controller, then you won't get this error and your table will be sortable. Also, your results will be paginated - at the moment I don't think they will be.